# Oracle Enterprise Server SOAP/Servlet/SoapRouter

Tags: oracle, soap, oas

Does anyone know any sample Oracle SOAP XML requests that that queries the database?

For example, the url: 
http://myoracle:7778/oracle/soap/soaprouter/

I'd like to program xml requests and get return xml database.
But I have no idea on the Oracle SOAP format.

Please provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation here goes into detail about the Oracle Application Server SOAP format:

http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14027/oraclesoap.htm

It looks like it is based on Apache 2.3.1 SOAP with some minor enhancements.

You would need to create your own service (the code to fetch data from the database), then expose this web service so you can send SOAP requests to it and get responses back.  Some sample services are mentioned in the docs and should be included with the application server.